# Update constraints menu all greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode6, constraints

When I try to update constraints in Xcode 6.3, I can't because the menu is completely or partially greyed out.
http://hostthenpost.com/uploads/aa150beda71316c338da81c5e301d149.png

Why is this? How do I fix it? The app is a basic, simple Hello World app with two UIImageView elements both sharing heights and widths, and one is constrained 50 from the left, the other 50 from the right. What is wrong with it? How to I make it so I can update the constraints?

Edit: This is when I can see some, but not all of the constraints options.
http://hostthenpost.com/uploads/2d8a3bec6a17524d6f9ca1524c95fb0c.png

Answer (score 4):

That happens when you have a wrong item selected, meaning for example a constraint instead of the view or a subview.

To fix it, just select the view again. Then the options should show up again.

Still some options will be grayed out, if they would have no effect when clicked. For example `Update Frames` will only be available if there are actually *are* frames to be updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the view"? Sorry, I'm a total noob to this stuff.

Comment: I just mean that you should click on some ui object, not on a constraint or controller or somerhing else. Click on a view, a label, a button, just any ui object that you previously added

Answer (score 3):

If you clicked on the main `view` and then on the constraints button, you have to know that **you can't adding constraints from the main view in the storyboard, to its superview**. You can do this just by code.

If you are trying to **change the constraints for any other subviews**, please be sure to **click with the mouse on the object in the view**, and then on the constraints button.